# Azure Service Bus Topic Subscription REST API

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

How do I use Azure REST APIs to subscribe to a service bus topic? I want to create a subscription with "Enable Sessions" as the ordering of messages is very important for me. I have the below code that works now, that registers a message handler.

```
subscriptionClient.RegisterSessionHandler(ProcessMessagesInSessionAsync, sessionHandlerOptions);
```

However, I want to implement this using REST API. Is this possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "using REST"? When using the SDK it creates an open and steady connection using AMQP (by default) to the Service Bus to get notified immediately of new messages.

Comment: I 'm referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/service-bus-runtime-rest. I'm aware of SDK, but checking if I can retrieve messages from a session enabled Subscription using REST.